# How "allow-private-response-caching" works for http headers and shared cache

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

The msdn document ["API Management caching policies"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn894086.aspx) mentions `allow-private-response-caching`. But there is not much in the documentaion about its behaviors.

1. How is the http headers are generated with `allow-private-response-caching`?
2. How shared cache can cache this?
3. How is the authorisation validated in shared cache?

Comment: Reference: [channel9.msdn.com- Azure API Management Policy Expressions 103 - Caching and Output Conversion](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Azure-Friday/Azure-API-Management-Policy-Expressions-103-Caching-and-Output-Conversion)

Answer (score 4):

As documentation suggests this setting merely controls whether requests with Authorization header set considered cacheable, nothing more, everything else functions the same in this policy.

Given the shared nature of cache it is possible to misconfigure policy in such a way that cached data from one user would be given to another user from cache. So if you response content depends on who called API, and you want to use caching, I'd recommend to include Authorization header to vary-by-heade setting.